# Why does my Game Object get deleted when placed on my plate Kitchen Object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game objects keep getting deleted once placed on the plate Kitchen Object and not anything else and this is probably due to me implement a new thing into my code to detect which Kitchen Object is on the plate.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlateCompleteVisual : MonoBehaviour
{

    [Serializable]
    public struct KitchenObjectSO_GameObject
    {
        public KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
        public GameObject gameObject;
    }


    [SerializeField] private PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject;
    public List<KitchenObjectSO_GameObject> kitchenObjectSOGameObjectList;

    private void Start()
    {
    
    }

    

}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using static KitchenObjectType;
using static PlateCompleteVisual;

public class KitchenObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Bread,
        Lettuce,
        Cheese,
        Tomato,
        // Add more types as needed
    }

    public static void IdentifyKitchenObject(ObjectType objectType)
    {
        switch (objectType)
        {
            case ObjectType.Bread:
                Debug.Log("Found bread!");
                // Handle bread-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Lettuce:
                Debug.Log("Found lettuce!");
                // Handle lettuce-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Cheese:
                Debug.Log("Found cheese!");
                // Handle cheese-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Tomato:
                Debug.Log("Found tomato!");
                // Handle tomato-specific logic
                break;
            // Add cases for other types as needed
            default:
                Debug.Log("Unknown kitchen object type!");
                break;
        }
    }


    [SerializeField] KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
    private IKitchenObjectParent kitchenObjectParent;
   

    public KitchenObjectSO GetKitchenObjectSO()
    { 
        return kitchenObjectSO; 
    }

    public void SetKitchenObjectParent(IKitchenObjectParent KitchenObjectParent)
    {
        if (this.kitchenObjectParent != null)
        {
            this.kitchenObjectParent.ClearKitchenObject();
        }

        this.kitchenObjectParent = KitchenObjectParent;
        KitchenObjectParent.SetKitchenObject(this);

        if (KitchenObjectParent.HasKitchenObject())
        {
            Debug.LogError("IKitchenObjectParent already has a kitchen object");
        }
 
        transform.parent = KitchenObjectParent.GetKitchenObjectFollowTransform();
        transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
    public IKitchenObjectParent GetKitchenObjectParent()
    {
        return kitchenObjectParent;
    }

    public void DestroySelf()
    {
        kitchenObjectParent.ClearKitchenObject();
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public bool TryGetPlate(out PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject)
    {
        if (this is PlateKitchenObject)
        {
            plateKitchenObject = this as PlateKitchenObject;
            return true;
        }else
        {
            plateKitchenObject = null;
            return false;
        }
        
    }

    public static KitchenObject SpawnKitchenObject(KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO, IKitchenObjectParent kitchenObjectParent)
    {
        Transform kitchenObjectTransform = Instantiate(kitchenObjectSO.prefab);

        if (kitchenObjectTransform == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("Failed to instantiate kitchen object from prefab: " + kitchenObjectSO.prefab.name);
            return null;
        }

        KitchenObject kitchenObject = kitchenObjectTransform.GetComponent<KitchenObject>();

        if (kitchenObject == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("KitchenObject component not found on instantiated object. Adding the component...");

            // If KitchenObject component is not present, add it
            kitchenObject = kitchenObjectTransform.gameObject.AddComponent<KitchenObject>();
        }

        kitchenObject.SetKitchenObjectParent(kitchenObjectParent);
        return kitchenObject;
    }

    public void CheckForLettuceWithoutOther()
    {
        // Assuming PlateCompleteVisual is attached to a GameObject in the scene
        PlateCompleteVisual plateCompleteVisual = FindObjectOfType<PlateCompleteVisual>();

        if (plateCompleteVisual != null)
        {
            foreach (PlateCompleteVisual.KitchenObjectSO_GameObject kitchenObjectSOGameObject in plateCompleteVisual.kitchenObjectSOGameObjectList)
            {
                // Perform necessary logic here
            }
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public struct KitchenObjectSO_GameObject
    {
        public KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
        public GameObject gameObject;
    }

    [SerializeField] private PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject;
    [SerializeField] private List<KitchenObjectSO_GameObject> kitchenObjectSOGameObjectList;

    private void Start()
    {
        plateKitchenObject.OnIngredientAdded += PlateKitchenObject_OnIngredientAdded;

    }

    private void PlateKitchenObject_OnIngredientAdded(object sender, PlateKitchenObject.OnIngredientAddedEventArgs e)
    {        
        
        foreach (KitchenObjectSO_GameObject kitchenObjectSOGameObject in kitchenObjectSOGameObjectList)
        {
            if (kitchenObjectSOGameObject.kitchenObjectSO == e.kitchenObjectSO)
            {
                kitchenObjectSOGameObject.gameObject.SetActive(true);

                KitchenObjectType.IdentifyKitchenObject((KitchenObjectSO.ObjectType)(ObjectType)kitchenObjectSOGameObject.kitchenObjectSO.objectType);

            }
        }

    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class KitchenObjectType : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Bread,
        Lettuce,
        Cheese,
        Tomato,
        // Add more types as needed
    }

    public static void IdentifyKitchenObject(ObjectType objectType)
    {
        switch (objectType)
        {
            case ObjectType.Bread:
                Debug.Log("Found bread!");
                // Handle bread-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Lettuce:
                Debug.Log("Found lettuce!");
                // Handle lettuce-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Cheese:
                Debug.Log("Found cheese!");
                // Handle cheese-specific logic
                break;
            case ObjectType.Tomato:
                Debug.Log("Found tomato!");
                // Handle tomato-specific logic
                break;
            // Add cases for other types as needed
            default:
                Debug.Log("Unknown kitchen object type!");
                break;
        }
    }

    internal static void IdentifyKitchenObject(KitchenObjectSO.ObjectType objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public static explicit operator KitchenObject.ObjectType(KitchenObjectType v)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlateKitchenObject : KitchenObject
{

    public event EventHandler<OnIngredientAddedEventArgs> OnIngredientAdded;

    public class OnIngredientAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
    }


    [SerializeField] private List<KitchenObjectSO> validKitchenObjectList;
    private List<KitchenObjectSO> kitchenObjectSOList;

    private void Awake()
    {
        kitchenObjectSOList = new List<KitchenObjectSO>();
    }

    public bool TryAddIngredient(KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO)
    {
        if (!validKitchenObjectList.Contains(kitchenObjectSO))
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (kitchenObjectSOList.Contains(kitchenObjectSO))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {

            OnIngredientAdded?.Invoke(this, new OnIngredientAddedEventArgs
            {
                kitchenObjectSO = kitchenObjectSO
            });
            kitchenObjectSOList.Add(kitchenObjectSO);

            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BaseCounter : MonoBehaviour, IKitchenObjectParent
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform counterTopPoint;

    private KitchenObject kitchenObject;

    public virtual void InteractAlternate(Player player)
    {
        Debug.LogError("BaseCounter.Interact();");
    }

    public virtual void Interact(Player player)
    {
        Debug.LogError("BaseCounter.Interact();");
    }

    public Transform GetKitchenObjectFollowTransform()
    {
        return counterTopPoint;
    }

    public void SetKitchenObject(KitchenObject kitchenObject)
    {
        this.kitchenObject = kitchenObject;
    }

    public KitchenObject GetKitchenObject()
    {
        return kitchenObject;
    }

    public void ClearKitchenObject()
    {
        kitchenObject = null;
    }

    public bool HasKitchenObject()
    {
        return kitchenObject != null;
    }
}
```

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class ClearCounter : BaseCounter
    {
        [SerializeField] private KitchenObjectSO kitchenObjectSO;
        public override void Interact(Player player)
        {
            if (!HasKitchenObject())
            {
                if (player.HasKitchenObject())
                {
                  
    player.GetKitchenObject().SetKitchenObjectParent(this);                                                                                         
            }
            else
            {
            }
        }
            else
        {
            if (player.HasKitchenObject()) 
            {
                if (player.GetKitchenObject().TryGetPlate(out PlateKitchenObject plateKitchenObject))
                {
                    if (plateKitchenObject.TryAddIngredient(GetKitchenObject().GetKitchenObjectSO()))
                    {
                        GetKitchenObject().DestroySelf();
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (GetKitchenObject().TryGetPlate(out  plateKitchenObject))
                    {
                       if (plateKitchenObject.TryAddIngredient(player.GetKitchenObject().GetKitchenObjectSO()))
                       {
                            player.GetKitchenObject().DestroySelf();
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                GetKitchenObject().SetKitchenObjectParent(player);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Clear Kitchen Object just isnt used in the part that i gave.

Comment: If you want to find out what exactly is happening - simply place a `private void OnDestroy(){ Debug.LogError("I was just destroyed! o.O"); }` and then either check the stacktrace in the log console or additionally use breakpoints in your IDE and [Debug your code!](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html)

Comment: Bug finder, I started coding like a few weeks ago so i might not understand much or be efficient. Even though that is no excuse I still just wanted to mention that that's probably why its so messy.

Comment: its not the mess - can cope with that - its the you're asking us what happens when.. but not showing us the bit that does it.. just 2 classes it might be using

Comment: Ok i changed it.

Comment: I think the error is occuring in the clear counter script

Comment: Don't get discouraged by outrageously unfriendly responses by people like BugFinder. There are plenty friendly people here on SO who are willing to help:) Still, it helps if you clearly state your problem and provide us with minimal but sufficient code resources to your problem. I would recommend just like @derHugo to set breakpoints in Visual Studio, start Debug Mode and go through your code step by step. The section "Attach your code editor to the Unity Player" on [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) page describes the basic procedure. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thank you anjelomerte I will do that!

Comment: Nevermind everyone. My code has gotten better and i have made a better system. It is now working